# cannot have space when exceding three integer with f:converternumber jsf2

Tags: jsf-2, numbers, format, converters, floating

I want to see all number like that : `123 456.67` : a space when I exceeded 3 integer and always two fractions number

I tested that :

`<f:view contentType="text/html" locale="en" encoding="UTF-8">`

and that on each inputText :

```
<p:column headerText="Ajust Prix">
            <h:inputText value="#{car2.ajustPrix}" >
            <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" maxFractionDigits="2"  />
            </h:inputText>
        </p:column>
```

but I don't have the space when exceeding three integer,

how can I resolve this

Answer (score 1):

The `pattern` attribute of `<f:convertNumber>` uses the java formatting patterns that can be found in javadocs for [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). With the pattern you may specify the so-called 'grouping separator', which is what you're after. Also, it's worth reading some tutorials on the subject, like [Oracle's one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).

All in all, you need to use the following pattern: `#,##0.00`. It can be used like this:

```
<f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00" />
```

Comment: I tested that with locale="bg" it works for thousand number but  "."  is replaced by "," : I want "123 456.78" but I have "123 456,78"